# How can I determine which process owns a hotkey in Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

Given a hotkey, how can I find which program owns it?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**Caution**: If you use Win 8 or later, do not use this utility as it will create some trouble - see comments.

If you are running a Windows ***earlier* than Windows 8**, then [`Windows Hotkey Explorer`](http://hkcmdr.anymania.com/) is probably what you want. This is also mentioned in the StackOverflow question: [*Find out what process registered a global hotkey? (Windows API)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829007/find-out-what-process-registered-a-global-hotkey-windows-api/834661).

Comment: If Hotkey Explorer reports hotkey as `explorer.exe (TaskBar)` then probably one of icons on desktop has this hotkey set in its properties.

Comment: HotKey explorer screws up pretty badly in Windows 8 - on startup it basically "presses" every hotkey, causing all kinds of weird stuff to happen, after which it locks up and has to be killed.

Comment: Also pretty screwy on Windows 7.  It switched my main monitor's resolution to 640x480 (multi monitor set up).

Comment: @Flion: so do I. I have started a thread over at SwRec: [*How to list all current Windows Hotkeys?*](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/33669/how-to-list-all-current-windows-hotkeys)

Answer (score 116):

This works for me in Win10 (and probably all other even vaguely-recent versions of Windows)... also copied here from https://stackoverflow.com/a/43645062/995048 since this page seems to come up first in search results:

> One possible way is to use the [**Visual Studio tool Spy++**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/introducing-spy-increment?view=vs-2017).
>
> Give this a try:
>
> 1. Run the tool (for me, it's at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\Tools\spyxx_amd64.exe`, or use `spyxx.exe` to monitor 32-bit processes)
> 2. In the menu bar, select *Spy* -> *Log messages...* (or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>)
> 3. Check *All Windows in System* in the *Additional Windows* frame
> 4. Switch to the *Messages* tab
> 5. Click the *Clear All* button
> 6. Select `WM_HOTKEY` in the listbox, or check *Keyboard* in *Message Groups* (if you're OK with more potential noise)
> 7. Click the *OK* button
> 8. Press the hotkey in question (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, for example)
> 9. Select the `WM_HOTKEY` line in the *Messages (All Windows)* window, right click, and select *Properties...* in the context menu
> 10. In the *Message Properties* dialog, click the *Window Handle* link (this will be the handle for the window that received the message)
> 11. Click the *Synchronize* button on the *Window Properties* dialog.  This will show the window in the main Spy++ window treeview.
> 12. On the *Window Properties* dialog, select the *Process* tab
> 13. Click the *Process ID* link.  This will show you the process (In my <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> case: `EXPLORER`)

Comment: This is a great answer, it is a lot of steps but gives perfectly detailed information. Note that you will need to install SPY++ somehow and that you need to run the 64bit version on a 64bit PC or it won't work. I think the 'easiest' way to install SPY++ is to install Visual Studio 2017, be sure to select the C++ payload. For non developers this might be a bit too much work.

Comment: Great answer! Just a note that **the 64-bit version of Spy++ catches only messages for 64-bit applications**, so if you don't see the `WM_HOTKEY` message in the _Message log_ after pressing the hotkey, you may need to run the 32-bit version of Spy++.

Comment: Link should be updated to [new documentation site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/introducing-spy-increment). For Visual Studio 2017, the only required payload is "*Visual C++ core desktop features*". Application specific hotkey is not logged? For example, Ctrl + B in MS Word will make the text bold.

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  I FINALLY found out what was stealing Ctrl Shift F from me.  (It was Razer Cortex).  Another note is that sometimes spy++ will crash when you try to view the properties.  (And then you cannot see any more hooks until rebooting.)  I was able to resolve this by right clicking, before step 9, and choosing "Stop Logging Message".  At that point, it no longer crashed when I attempted to examine the properties.  Thanks again!

Comment: You can download it from https://github.com/westoncampbell/SpyPlusPlus, http://mdb-blog.blogspot.com/2017/02/download-microsoft-spy-140-2016-06-20.html.

Comment: Suggestion: add to the answer that you can get the latest version of SpyPlusPlus from official sources by downloading the community edition of Visual Studio at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/ (I cannot edit the answer myself ...)

Comment: In case it helps anyone else, my following these steps caused Spy++ to crash, with an error "Spy++ has encountered a problem in the message hook. To prevent hanging the system, the hook has been disabled, so no further messages will be logged." Recommended restart (x86 and x64) changes nothing. Event viewer shows a fault 0xc0000005 (which appears to be IE related, and yes, this #%!#% hotkey is invoking IE)

Comment: I didn't get any `WM_HOTKEY` events but I did notice a lack of `WM_KEYDOWN` events for the keys I cared about. This led to github issues with the solution which in my case was Parsec eating Ctrl+F1  and Ctrl+F3. Might be worth trying out if you can't see any `WM_HOTKEY` messages!

Comment: Thank you for this!! I haven't been able to type '0' using the regular 0 key (#48) on any keyboard on one of my machines for aaaages. I've always had to use a numpad (#96) if the keyboard has one, or copy-paste an existing 0 if not, and this even applied to the built-in windows OSK... Turns out, at some point I had accidentally assigned '0' to something in NVIDIA ShadowPlay settings. I would never have found that. And given that it has persisted for years through a video card change and numerous other hardware upgrades, it clearly would have persisted until I nuked and paved the OS.

Comment: The message above @DavidFerenczyRogožan 's comment ("you need to run the 64bit version on a 64bit PC or it won't work") seems to contradict what they're saying, "so if you don't see the WM_HOTKEY message in the Message log after pressing the hotkey, you may need to run the 32-bit version of Spy++". Does anyone know which is true?

Comment: You should run the version of Spy++ that matches the architecture of the app that captured the key.  Since that's unknown, you may end up needing to try both.  My experience is that the 64bit version of Spy++ won't find 32bit windows.  I've just verified that.  You will need the 32bit version if a 32bit app registered the hotkey.

Answer (score 67):

I've recently wrote a small utility - **Hotkey Detective** - for newer Windows versions (tested on 8.1 and 10). It simply shows what process owns the hotkey when you trigger the keystroke.

As distinct from other known tools, like **Hotkey Explorer**, my utility doesn't list all hotkeys, because that would involve artificial triggering all of them, and breaking the system in the end. In order to see what process is the guilty one, simply run my utility **with administrator privileges** and press the stolen hotkey. That's all.

Hotkey Detective's sources and a quick usage manual can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/ITachiLab/hotkey-detective). The [binary releases](https://github.com/ITachiLab/hotkey-detective/releases) are there too.

[image]

This is an early beta, so report any issues if you find them.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me, just remember to run as admin and try both x64 and x86 if you can't get it listed. The readme explains it, I just didn't read it at first :-)

Comment: This works perfectly for me too! Great utility

Comment: I'm on Windows 10, i've tried both x64 and x86 versions, both with admin privileges, and it does not show the stolen hotkey. I'm trying to use Ctrl+D in VS Code, and this combination just won't register.

Comment: Yes! Thank you good man! It helped mi solve the problem with CTRL + ALT + S not printing polish letter ś. 

Some keywords in here to help others find this solution easier: "Snipping Tool, litera ś, problem z pisaniem litery ś, Evernote".

Comment: Works beautifully - thank you!

Comment: I was going crazy trying to understand why certain shortcuts didn't work in a game. Your utility helped me find the culprit (thanks for nothing, AMD Radeon software...). Many thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This has probably been answered on Stack Overflow in this thread:

[Find out what process registered a global hotkey? (Windows API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829007/find-out-what-process-registered-a-global-hotkey-windows-api/887086#887086)

Here's [Pauk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17461/pauk)'s answer:

> Your question piqued my interest, so I've done a bit of digging and
> while, unfortunately I don't have a proper answer for you, I thought
> I'd share what I have.
>
> I found this [example of creating keyboard hook (in Delphi)](http://groups.google.com/group/borland.public.delphi.winapi/msg/ceb5818acd623a24)
> written in 1998, but is compilable in Delphi 2007 with a couple of
> tweaks.
>
> It's a DLL with a call to `SetWindowsHookEx` that passes through a
> callback function, which can then intercept key strokes: In this case,
> it's tinkering with them for fun, changing left cursor to right, etc.
> A simple app then calls the DLL and reports back its results based on
> a TTimer event. If you're interested I can post the Delphi 2007 based
> code.
>
> It's well documented and commented and you potentially could use it as
> a basis of working out where a key press is going. If you could get
> the handle of the application that sent the key strokes, you could
> track it back that way. With that handle you'd be able to get the
> information you need quite easily.
>
> Other apps have tried determining hotkeys by going through their
> Shortcuts since they can contain a Shortcut key, which is just another
> term for hotkey. However most applications don't tend to set this
> property so it might not return much. If you are interested in that
> route, Delphi has access to `IShellLink` COM interface which you could
> use to load a shortcut up from and get its hotkey:
>
> ```delphi
> uses ShlObj, ComObj, ShellAPI, ActiveX, CommCtrl;
>
> procedure GetShellLinkHotKey;
> var
>   LinkFile : WideString;
>   SL: IShellLink;
>   PF: IPersistFile;
>
>   HotKey : Word;
>   HotKeyMod: Byte;
>   HotKeyText : string;
> begin
>   LinkFile := 'C:\Temp\Temp.lnk';
>
>   OleCheck(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IShellLink, SL));
>
>   // The IShellLink implementer must also support the IPersistFile
>   // interface. Get an interface pointer to it.
>   PF := SL as IPersistFile;
>
>   // Load file into IPersistFile object
>   OleCheck(PF.Load(PWideChar(LinkFile), STGM_READ));
>
>   // Resolve the link by calling the Resolve interface function.
>   OleCheck(SL.Resolve(0, SLR_ANY_MATCH or SLR_NO_UI));
>
>   // Get hotkey info
>   OleCheck(SL.GetHotKey(HotKey));
>
>   // Extract the HotKey and Modifier properties.
>   HotKeyText := '';
>   HotKeyMod := Hi(HotKey);
>
>   if (HotKeyMod and HOTKEYF_ALT) = HOTKEYF_ALT then
>     HotKeyText := 'ALT+';
>   if (HotKeyMod and HOTKEYF_CONTROL) = HOTKEYF_CONTROL then
>     HotKeyText := HotKeyText + 'CTRL+';
>   if (HotKeyMod and HOTKEYF_SHIFT) = HOTKEYF_SHIFT then
>     HotKeyText := HotKeyText + 'SHIFT+';
>   if (HotKeyMod and HOTKEYF_EXT) = HOTKEYF_EXT then
>     HotKeyText := HotKeyText + 'Extended+';
>
>   HotKeyText := HotKeyText + Char(Lo(HotKey));
>
>   if (HotKeyText = '') or (HotKeyText = #0) then
>     HotKeyText := 'None';
>
>   ShowMessage('Shortcut Key - ' + HotKeyText);
> end;
> ```
>
> If you've got access to [Safari Books Online](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/), there is a [good
> section about working with shortcuts / shell links](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/0672321157/ch16lev1sec3) in the Borland
> Delphi 6 Developer's Guide by Steve Teixeira and Xavier Pacheco. My
> example above is a butchered version from there and [this site](http://delphicikk.atw.hu/listaz.php?id=2351&oldal=1).
>
> Hope that helps!

Answer (score 6):

I must recommend [OpenArk](https://github.com/BlackINT3/OpenArk). Under "Kernel" tab, "System Hotkey" page, you can find all registered hotkeys and corresponding processes. Remember to click "Enter KernelMode" button first.

Answer (score 1):

These answers didn't work for me because--if I understand correctly--the hotkey had just been dropped on a `.lnk` that did not get removed on an uninstall. Spy++ crashed when it was invoked.

Following the steps on [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1320005) solved it: find the shortcut in question (mine was hiding in the start menu, without showing up under windows start button for whatever reason) and remove its hotkey setting (using backspace) or just delete the shortcut altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I use Ctrl-Shift-C and Ctrl-Shift-V to copy and paste formatting in Word in win10. AMD's Radeon Pro Software robbed the Ctrl-Shift-C keyboard shortcut to enable/disable the camera. I disabled all hotkeys in the Radeon software and got the functionality back for Word, but one could reassign only the camera portion, or any other conflicting hotkey if one wanted to retain the Radeon hotkey function.