# How do I get the list of defined shortcut keys in the Start menu?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, start-menu

How can I find out which keyboard shortcuts are defined inside the *Start* menu? And what shortcuts they are assigned to?

Platform: Windows XP SP2 64 bit.

---

Example:

I open my main Visual Studio solution with a shortcut key,
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>. This is set up
by having a shortcut inside the Start menu with:

```
Target: "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" D:\dproj\MSQall\MSQuant\MSQuant.sln

Shortcut key: Ctrl+ALT+M
```

If a new shortcut is added and its shortcut key is also set
to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> then there
are now two shortcuts with the same shortcut key (conflict).
To prevent this it would be nice to know which shortcut keys
are already assigned and to which shortcuts.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like [ActiveHotkeys](http://www.donationcoder.com/Forums/bb/index.php?PHPSESSID=srmnjbd1ssvqvp65rthk00f844&topic=18189.msg162881#msg162881) might be what you want:

> On several occasions there have been
>   requests for a program that displays
>   what global keyboard shortcuts are
>   registered by various applications.
>   ActiveHotkeys does just that: it will
>   show a list of all active (registered)
>   or inactive (available) global
>   hotkeys.
>
> Updated to version 1.1 - the
>   Play/Pause edition. Totally free for
>   all; please let me know if you
>   encounter a problem. No installation
>   necessary - just unpack and run. See
>   the included readme file for details
>   (or click the About tab in the
>   program).
>
> Download links are at the bottom of
>   this post. Please be sure to download
>   the latest version.
>
> Please note that Windows does not
>   allow for detecting which application
>   has registered a particular shortcut,
>   so that feaure is not included. (If
>   you think you know how to achieve
>   that, using message hooks or what-not,
>   please post here or [earn some karma at
>   StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829007/find-out-what-process-registered-a-global-hotkey-windows-api))

[image: Main Screen of ActiveHotkeys]

Comment: I just downloaded and tried it. It is very useful although it does not locate the shortcut. But at least it can be used to find out which shortcut keys are free, including the Windows key ones, e.g. Win+A.

Comment: Yeah, reading through the linked StackOverflow post, it doesn't look like there's any way to see what programs have grabbed what shortcuts.

Answer (score 5):

There is a utility that helps you see which programs have grabbed which shortcut. It is called [Shortcuts Map](http://www.zealsoftstudio.com/shortcuts/) from Zealsoft.

Comment: Running a Chinese SETUP.exe... not feeling too good about it...

Comment: this is not what you want. This program looks at shortcut (.lnk) files. Not Keyboard shortcuts

Answer (score 1):

http://hkcmdr.anymania.com/help.html

To the left, there should be a link that says "Download Windows Hotkey Explorer Free!". This did the trick for me. It showed that "Cisco IP Communicator" was using Ctrl+Shift+A as a global hotkey when I needed it to work as "Add New Item" in Visual Studio.

Comment: Don't use Hotkey Explorer with Windows 8 or 10 or you will be sorry. See http://superuser.com/a/191090/2173 and https://plus.google.com/u/0/+ArtemRussakovskii/posts/X4DDdY1fbye for reasons why.