# Shortcut Keys Issue

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts

I created some custom keyboard shortcut keys for some of the file shortcuts,
But after I deleted above mentioned file shortcuts, I cannot assign the keyboard shortcut keys associated with old ones to any new file shortcuts,
How do I fix this?
Also is there any application available that shows all the current assigned keyboard shortcut keys?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Whenever this happens to me, a simple reboot frees up the keyboard shortcuts previously assigned so I can reassign them.

As for the second part of your question, see if this helps: [How do I get the list of defined shortcut keys in the Start menu?](https://superuser.com/questions/26824/how-to-get-list-of-defined-shortcut-keys-in-the-start-menu)