# How can I know what keyboard combination shortcuts are currently set in my computer ?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have  many keyboard shortcuts in my pc (windows 7 , 64 bit) .

I set those keyboard shortcuts  to the "*shortcut*" of the program/script.

For example , if I want to run chrome via <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> then I go to

[image]

**Question**

Since I have many shortcuts like these , I forgot some.

Is there any way to see all current assigned keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: Check out the answers here and let us know if that covers you: [How to get list of defined shortcut keys in the Start menu?](http://superuser.com/questions/26824/how-to-get-list-of-defined-shortcut-keys-in-the-start-menu) - (specifically I'm thinking [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/26844/23133))

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 This is not showing the actual program that the key sequence invoke.

Comment: You're question was "Is there any way to see all current assigned keyboard shortcuts?", not "what they're assigned to". :) For that, see other existing SU questions like: [How can I determine which process owns a hotkey in Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/11308/how-can-i-determine-which-process-owns-a-hotkey-in-windows)