# Displaying all Windows 10 Hotkeys - possible?

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys

Is there anyway to display all of the current hotkeys my windows 10 currently have?

I don't want to search online for the default list, because I might changed some hotkeys, and I don't want to go and search each program or any combination of a hotkey to understand what it does - that's why I'm looking for an easy list that shows all of my current Windows hotkeys.

Is it possible?

Comment: Is [this](http://superuser.com/a/26844/164837) what you looking for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get list of defined shortcut keys in the Start menu?](http://superuser.com/questions/26824/how-to-get-list-of-defined-shortcut-keys-in-the-start-menu)