# How to find which program captures global keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I determine which process owns a hotkey in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/11308/how-can-i-determine-which-process-owns-a-hotkey-in-windows)

Some of my global shortcuts stopped working, and I cannot figure out why. I suspect that there is some program that captures these shortcuts, but I don't know how to figure out which one is it (if any). Using windows7rc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you'll have some luck with [Deep System Explorer](http://tds.diamondcs.com.au/dse/features.php). They list Hotkeys in the features they support.

I couldn't run it on my Windows 7 64-bits after install (driver error), not sure wich version (32 or 64 bits) of 7 you're using.

Another one, [HotKey Commander](http://hkcmdr.anymania.com/index.html), is listed in [this thread](http://forum.sysinternals.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=18909) at Sysinternals.

Comment: Thank you. Deep System Explorer seems to be able to get this information. I will try it on the system where I see the problem.

Comment: I installed and openend Hotkey Commander. It opened _all_ programs I have on my computer, which obviously made it crash and led me to believe that that is shady software.

Comment: Hotkey Commander/Explorer is just badly coded. It scans for every possible shortcut, and actually executes each of them in doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be tricky. Found [Active Hotkeys](http://www.donationcoder.com/Forums/bb/index.php?topic=18189.msg162881) which will tell you *if* a hotkey has been assigned. This led to [his Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829007/find-out-what-process-registered-a-global-hotkey-windows-api) which has been asked by the developer. Not sure I understand the answers, but good luck in there!