# How do I disable specific windows 10/Office Keyboard Shortcut (CTRL+SHIFT+WIN+ALT+D)

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-office, autohotkey

it seems that Office has decided to hi-jack the keyboard shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

That might not seem like a problem, but I have assigned that keyboard shortcut in AutoHotKey and have been using it for years.

It started opening the Office Hub, and after I uninstalled that, it now opens the Office Hub web page instead.

So, how do I remove/disable this keyboard shortcut?

There are no Office processes running, and I can't find any `.lnk` files that might have a shortcut assigned in properties.

Any ideas?

I am using the latest Windows Insider Preview (18932) and latest Office with all updates installed.

Comment: With me this shortcut open up the OneDrive folder.

Comment: I have noticed that there is the similar thread from you in TechNet forum. I will continue to pay attention to this issue there.

Comment: duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1455857/how-to-disable-office-key-keyboard-shortcut-opening-office-app

Answer (score 31):

Just upgraded to Windows 1903 and hit this myself, seems Microsoft decided to assign the keyboard shortcut for the new Office App to Win+Ctrl+Alt+Shift!

Changing the open command for this to rundll32 resolved the issue for me.  Using an elevated cmd, run the following command:

```
    REG ADD HKCU\Software\Classes\ms-officeapp\Shell\Open\Command /t REG_SZ /d rundll32
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Your tip finally allowed me to turn the winkeys back on: I used Win+Ctrl+Alt+Shift key combos with Autohotkey and didn't want to edit my scripts to resolve the conflict with this new stupid office shortcut

Comment: As a user who had completely uninstalled all the Office stuff, I confirm that this immediately disables the Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Win keyboard shortcut. Looks like it tries to open the ms-officeapp class with the single argument “Officekey”, and then if that fails, falls back to opening a website. And running `rundll32 Officekey` succeeds, doing nothing. This provides a convenient way to bind something else to the keyboard shortcut: set the value to something other than `rundll32`, and it’ll run that command. (Just remember the extra argument it passes.)

Comment: This doesn't work for me in 1909. :(

Comment: Works in Windows 10 version 2004 (Build 19041.630)

Comment: As a contributor to the AHK community, let me say thanks for posting this. Fantastic solution!

Answer (score 7):

[AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com) can be used to override most keyboard shortcuts - generally the only exceptions are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

One complication in this case is that AutoHotkey does not block the modifier keys, since doing so would interfere with their normal function. For example, the hotkey `^!+#d::` would suppress the <kbd>D</kbd> key, but only after the four modifier keys have already been passed through to the OS and the active window. In effect, the operating system's keyboard shortcut recognizer sees only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, so instead of opening OneDrive, it opens the Office app or website.

The same generally applies to the Win and Alt keys, which normally activate the Start menu or a window menu. However, in those cases AutoHotkey automatically "masks" the menu by sending a key (<kbd>LCtrl</kbd> by default, but it can be overridden with [#MenuMaskKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_MenuMaskKey.htm)). After the operating system's keyboard shortcut recognizer sees that Win or Alt is used in combination with another key, it avoids activating the menu when the Win or Alt key is released.

A future update to AutoHotkey might add this masking for `^!+#`, but as of v1.1.30.03 it is not done. Masking the shortcut manually is just a case of sending a key.

## Disable OneDrive Shortcut (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Win+D)

The following script for AutoHotkey v1.x disables <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>:

```
^+!#d::
Send {blind}{vk07}
;... perform other tasks here as needed ...
return
```

## Disable Office Shortcut (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+Win)

Since the main Office shortcut can be activated by combining the modifier keys in any order, suppressing it requires several hotkeys; one for each "suffix" key:

```
#^!Shift::
#^+Alt::
#!+Ctrl::
^!+LWin::
^!+RWin::
Send {Blind}{vk07}
return
```

## Other Shortcuts

According to my experimentation on Windows 10 build 18362.10014, the following <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd> shortcuts also exist: <kbd>W</kbd>ord, <kbd>T</kbd>eams, <kbd>Y</kbd>ammer, <kbd>O</kbd>utlook/Mail, <kbd>P</kbd>owerPoint, <kbd>L</kbd>inkedIn, E<kbd>x</kbd>cel and One<kbd>N</kbd>ote.

## Which program snatches the keyboard shortcut?

It is likely that the letter-key shortcuts are handled in the same manner as all other hotkeys registered with [RegisterHotkey](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerhotkey); that is, they are registered by a program (Explorer in this case), and are deregistered when that program exits or is terminated.

- One can exit Explorer on Windows 10 and earlier by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>-right-clicking on the taskbar and selecting "Exit Explorer". Alternatively, Explorer can be terminated via Task Manager.
- If Explorer is not running when the script starts, the hotkey `^!+#d::` is typically able to be registered by AutoHotkey - `ListHotkeys` shows the "reg" method.
- If Explorer is running when the script starts, the hotkey `^!+#d::` cannot be registered, so AutoHotkey falls back to using the keyboard hook - `ListHotkeys` shows the "k-hook" method.
- If Explorer is restarted *after* the script has registered `^+!#d::` with RegisterHotkey, the built-in hotkey does not work *even if AutoHotkey is terminated*, until Explorer is restarted. This can be explained by the fact that RegisterHotkey will fail if the hotkey has already been registered by any process.

This can also be observed with the more traditional shortcuts, such as <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, but not <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, which is likely implemented at a lower level for security reasons.

However, the main Office shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>) does not behave this way, and cannot be disabled by simply defining a hotkey that does nothing. This is likely due to the fact that it activates when a modifier key is *released*, not when it is pressed.

The Office app does not appear to be responsible for registration of the shortcuts. If the Office app is "uninstalled" via the Settings app, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd> **reinstalls** the Office app and then opens it. If the app is [completely removed via PowerShell](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2112797-how-to-uninstall-microsoft-office-store-apps-completely), the shortcut opens the Office website instead.

On my system, the One<kbd>D</kbd>rive shortcut shows an error message (Windows cannot find OneDrive.exe) and then opens the OneDrive website, undoubtedly because I have uninstalled OneDrive.

## Admin Privileges

... are not needed for overriding system-defined hotkeys. However, if the active window is running at a higher integrity level than AutoHotkey, hotkeys implemented with the keyboard hook (such as all of the above) will typically not work. This is due to a security feature called [User Interface Privilege Isolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Interface_Privilege_Isolation), which can be bypassed by [Running with UI Access](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Program.htm#Installer_uiAccess). While running as admin grants admin privileges to the script and any programs that it launches, running with UI Access only permits the script to bypass UIPI.

Comment: **If** solution as in `Disable Office Shortcut` section, custom scripts `Ctrl+Alt+Win+Shift+any key` ([**example**](https://www.pastery.net/bfcmta/), [**purpose**](https://superuser.com/q/1147517/572069)) will not work. Thanks.

Comment: The AHK god himself making a post here. You're freaking awesome, Lexikos!!! Thanks yet again for another great in-depth explanation.

Answer (score 0):

If you know which program/task "snatches" the keyboard shortcut you should check if the task has higher permissions. For example if it runs with admin rights while AHK is running with regular user rights. In this case you should give AHK admin privileges as well which should solve your problem.

Since no office task is running a different task might be responsible for "shatching" the shortcut, there are a few [suggestion](https://superuser.com/questions/57041/how-to-find-which-program-captures-global-keyboard-shortcut) here on the site that will help you to find the responsible task.

Comment: Thanks Albin, I will take a look at the suggestions.
AHK is running with admin privileges already, so sadly that didn't help...
I also haven't been able to figure out exactly what it is that grabs the shortcut. I thought it was the OfficeHub app, but after uninstalling it, the shortcut is still snatched, but now takes me to the OfficeHub website instead.

Comment: @LarsPanzerbjrn I haven't used AHK in a while, but it might also be as easy as telling AHK to capture the shortcut before any other task. I'm not really sure how the capture is implemented, especially if there is a conflict, I would try to look for this kind of option within AHK first.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution that disables all of the shortcuts entirely.

https://www.howtogeek.com/445318/how-to-remap-the-office-key-on-your-keyboard/

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, wchar_t* argv[])
{
    //Build Array Of Keys To Unregister
    //These map to W, T, Y, O, P, D, L, X, N, and Space, respectively.
    UINT offendingKeys[10] = { 0x57, 0x54, 0x59, 0x4F, 0x50, 0x44, 0x4C, 0x58, 0x4E, 0x20 };

    //Kill Explorer
    system("taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F");

    //Register hotkey
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        RegisterHotKey(NULL, i, 0x1 + 0x2 + 0x4 + 0x8 | MOD_NOREPEAT, offendingKeys[i]);
    }

    //Restart Explorer
    system("start C:/Windows/explorer.exe");

    /* Sleep for a few seconds to make sure Explorer has time to
       attempt to register the Office hotkeys, and get blocked by 
       our hotkeys */
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(4000));

    //deregister hotkeys by ID
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        UnregisterHotKey(NULL, i);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Basically, Explorer is closed, then the program registers each hotkey. When Explorer restarts, it gets blocked by our hotkeys. The program deregisters the hotkeys and then exits, returning the keyboard to a usable state.

You'll need jfrmilner's registry tweak active for this to work:

```
REG ADD HKCU\Software\Classes\ms-officeapp\Shell\Open\Command /t REG_SZ /d rundll32
```

In my testing, I could not override hotkeys registered by Explorer while it was running, even running the script as administrator, so Explorer must be restarted which is a minor annoyance. If anyone knows of a way to override Explorer's hotkeys directly, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hyperenable](https://github.com/midrare/hyperenable).

*Disclaimer: I'm the author.*