# Disable Windows+Alt+D shortcut/hotkey displaying date and time popup/widget

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I need this hotkey functionality for another app. How can I disable Win+Alt+D from popping up the date/time/calendar/agenda popout so that I can use this shortcut in another program?

I have AutoHotkey and EventGhost installed. And Despite using EventGhost to emulate the keystroke combo for the active application, Windows 10 still grabs it and instead pops up this annoying calendar widget.

Seriously, if I ever needed that, I could just as easily click the calendar in the taskbar. :P

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I disable specific windows 10/Office Keyboard Shortcut (CTRL+SHIFT+WIN+ALT+D)](https://superuser.com/questions/1457073/how-do-i-disable-specific-windows-10-office-keyboard-shortcut-ctrlshiftwinal)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'll give it a try on Monday if I have time. Back at home now with no Windows 10 PC to test it on.

Comment: @Silbee I finally got around to looking into this again. Looks like I need to do a lot more than I expected - installing Visual Studio just so I can compile the cpp file needed to temporarily register hotkeys so Explorer can't when it is launched at startup. Too much trouble for now. I wish someone had just provided a compiled version of the file needed.