# Delete Global Hotkey

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

Is there any way I can delete a global hotkey? I don't want to override it, I want it just deleted, since it blocks the key combination's use in other applications.

I don't have knowledge of what the program is that has the registered hotkey, but I also don't want to have to deal with installing Delphi and learning the language as suggested in the answer to a similar question on stackoverflow.

Thanks.

Comment: A lot of info is missing! For starters, what OS?

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I determine which process owns a hotkey in Windows?](http://superuser.com/q/11308/664)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out with help from this program listed as ["Windows Hotkey Explorer Free!"](http://hkcmdr.anymania.com/)

which told me that it was Skype that had registered the hotkey. I'd really hate Skype if it wasn't so useful.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are talking about windows, and about a hotkey that was registered by some application with the [RegisterHotKey function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309%28VS.85%29.aspx) in the Windows API.

The answer is therefore to uninstall or reconfigure the application that is stealing the key input. It cannot steal the hotkey if it is not running.

I presume you have no trouble determining *which* application has registered the hotkey. After all, it should be the one currently responding with some action to the problematic hotkey.

Comment: Dang, because I actually don't know. The hotkey is registered, but does nothing.