# Windows 7 (64-bit) remove global hotkey created by unknown application

Tags: windows, hotkeys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Finding which process owns a hotkey in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/11308/finding-which-process-owns-a-hotkey-in-windows)

As the titles says an unknown application that I've installed have registered a global hot-key for Alt+2 , or as this is a Finnish keyboard it's actually Alt Gr+2. As this is also the key combination for writing the @ symbol (I copy/pasted this one) you can imagine how frustrating it is.

There doesn't seem to be a way to even list these global hot-keys in windows, let alone change them. Searching the net doesn't help much either, it just gives you a list of windows built-in hot-keys or references to AutoHotKey, which as far as I can tell can't solve this issue. I don't want to script/customize/modify anything, I just want to remove this global hot-key so I can start typing @ again.

Comment: What program, application, or action launches/occurs when you press this Hot Key now?  Anything?  Nothing?

You do not have a ThinkPad by chance do you?

Answer (score 2):

The program which has registered the hotkey must be running on your system. You can download a free program from [here](http://hkcmdr.anymania.com) which allows you to see which program has registered hotkeys. The full version of the program, which isn't free, says that it can disable or change the hotkey, but that should only be required if the program that uses the hotkey is needed and does not let you have a option to change it.

Works on Windows 7 (64-Bit), but it looks like is attempts to restart all your active programs in administrative mode in order to detect the hotkeys.