# Disable <ctrl + monitor#> screen switching functionality in Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, multiple-monitors

In Windows 7, when I have multiple monitors extending my desktop, there is functionality to activate a certain monitor by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[monitor #]</kbd>.  So if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, then the current program jumps over to the monitor identified as monitor 2.  I'm sure this functionality serves a good purpose, but it can be rather annoying in programs that rely on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[number]</kbd> for other functionality.

Is there a way to disable this feature in Windows?

Comment: [Ctrl]+[Number] as described is not not a Windows feature. Do you have any third party applications that may have assigned this hotkey? Perhaps graphics driver or display managing software?

Comment: Correct. By default, in Windows, you can move open windows across monitors using the Snap functionality, as described here: http://www.7tutorials.com/how-snap-windows-side-side-dual-multi-monitor-setup  You must have something installed that allows you to do what you described. Uninstalling it will "fix" your "issue".

Comment: maybe you should considering about use third party application. :)

Comment: Please see [How can I determine which process owns a hotkey in Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/11308/how-can-i-determine-which-process-owns-a-hotkey-in-windows) to find out what's causing this behaviour. You can add your own answer with what it turned out to be.

Answer (score 3):

Found the Super Utilities running in my notification area.
It’s the Multi-Display Control Panel utility where you can set the “Hotkey to move Window between Display”.

I simply reassigned the hotkeys for now.

Comment: can you clarify this a little more?

Comment: Thank you so much this was doing my nut in, as ctrl-1 is the keyboard short cut for auto fix in Eclipse...

Comment: @Malachi Right-click on the "Super Utility" icon in your system tray, select "Multi-Display Control Panel", click Disable.

Comment: 3 and a half years and I get a response!  lol thank you, I was hoping the answerer could incorporate more information into their answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for point me in the right direction, user137553.

Reassigning the keys didn't fix it for me, but I found that the MCTDUtil process was responsible for Super Utilities, and when I killed in via Process Explorer the problem when away.

I used CCleaner to disable MCTDUtil from getting launched at Startup, and my CTRL + 1 and CTRL + 2 hotkeys are working correctly now in Outlook and Firefox!

Answer (score 0):

This "utility" was switching my screens when I hit the hot keys, whether or not I was also holding down CTRL or ALT or SHIFT.

I couldn't find any way to directly uninstall it, but located the file responsible in this directory:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\DesktopUtil

I changed the name of the DesktopUtil folder to _old_DesktopUtil and now Super Utility no longer runs at startup. Headache solved.