# Disable CTRL+ALT+L in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I have recently noticed that in Windows 10, double combo <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> causes screen to lock, exactly like <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

I have noticed this happening since a while, maybe since `2004` update.

It is frustrating. I instinctively use the combo in IntelliJ IDEA to reformat files every time I finish editing them, but now the system intercepts the first combo and doesn't propagate it to IDEA.

Does anyone know how to disable this combo for lock screen?

---

Edit: seems like the situation is worse. I can't type `@` on my keyboard, in particular with the classic combo <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>@</kbd> (<kbd>ò</kbd>). In fact, <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> gets completely ignored even with euro <kbd>€</kbd> key.  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd> serves as <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>

I tried [Spy++](https://github.com/westoncampbell/SpyPlusPlus) but no process is stealing hotkeys

Comment: Why not turn it on its head, and change the key combination in IntelliJ?

Comment: I use the combo *instinctively* since years. It took me a lot of time to learn IDEA combos

Comment: You need to check [who's stealing that shortcut](https://superuser.com/q/449895/241386) because Ctrl+Alt+L is not mapped to Win+L in Windows 10

Comment: I tested Ctrl - Alt - Del with Windows 2004 Production and Windows 2004 5 or 6 months hence and Ctrl-Alt-Del the second time does not do anything more.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Closing app **Mouse without Borders** fixed the ctrl alt l issue, but not the @/€ issue

[From](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/mouse-without-borders-mousewithoutborders/0523308d-3406-4273-b86e-bef28aa6b50d)

> Lock/Unlock all machines at once

> Hit Ctrl+Alt+L twice to lock all machines. NOTE: If you use a Polish keyboard, Alt+L (to show up the 'ł' letter) would be eaten up in the remote machine so you would better change this hotkey to something else:)

Comment: No need to close the Mouse without borders app, just disable the `Lock machine` Shortcut in Settings>Other options

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use AutoHotKey (Download from https://www.autohotkey.com/) for this:

```
^!L::return
```

First Save this as .ahk file and run it. Now CTRL+ALT+L hotkey will be disabled.

Comment: this doesn't solve the root cause. If AHK captures the key after it was hooked then it won't work at all