# Shift+S and Shift+R not working

Tags: keyboard, windows-11

My <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> does not work but when I type shift with other keys it work and only work when I use <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>.

I have tried multiple method to fixed this problem but it doesn't work example: turn off sticky keys, reset my keyboard in device manager does not work this have happen for weeks now and am getting annoyed by it.

It will be a pleasure if someone could help me fix this.

Comment: Reset sticky keys to default and run DISM / SFC.  (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Comment: Have you tried another keyboard?

Comment: Is some application "stealing" Shift-R and Shift-S? For example, AutoHotKey or Clavier+ can use those key combos for some action.

Comment: @John do i put all those codes in when i open command promt?

Comment: @DavidPostill yes i have tried it but It didn't work

Comment: @DrMoishePippik no I don't

Comment: Follow each complete step (1) through (5) above . I cannot format comments.

Comment: @John I know but do I copy and paste what you type and put it in the command promt?

Comment: Open an admin command prompt and go through each step one at a time. Type in the command string.

Comment: @John alright now is verifying is verifying 5% complete but is taking a bit to long to go up a percent is that normal?

Comment: Each command takes time and all together a half hour or so.

Comment: @John alright I'll let you know when is done loading

Comment: @John is finish loading what do i do next?

Comment: Did you restart ?  The commands are repairs so they do not load. After restart, are the keys working?

Comment: @John I restart my laptop after it finish loading and it didn't work

Comment: See if you can make a bootable USB from Linux or such like.  Start the way and see if Shift S and Shift R work. If so, you probably are best advised to reinstall Windows.

Comment: @John I reinstall my window now is working perfectly fine thanks

Comment: So my answer was the solution and I will post an answer.

Comment: I made a note to iinclude reinstalling Windows,

Comment: try checking which app steals the keys: [How to determine which app is stealing (listening on) keystroke / key combination (Windows)?](https://superuser.com/q/449895/241386), [Find out what program is using a hotkey](https://superuser.com/q/999106/241386), [How can I determine which process owns a hotkey in Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/11308/241386)

Answer (score 1):

> my shift + s and shift + r does not work but when I type shift with
> other keys it work and only work when I use cap lock. can someone help
> me fixed this problem

Reset sticky keys to default and run DISM / SFC.

If DISM and SFC do not fix the problem, then you are likely best to reinstall Windows.

Note:  You said in a comment that you had reinstalled Windows to fix the issue.