# Shift+R not working in windows 11

Tags: keyboard, windows-11-v22h2

I am using Windows 11 Pro. The <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> key is not working but when the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> is turned on, it works fine. I have already tried the solutions mentioned in [Shift+S and Shift+R not working](https://superuser.com/questions/1692543/shifts-and-shiftr-not-working), but the problem still persists.
However, the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key works fine with all other keys except <kbd>R</kbd>. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen when you press shift-r?

Comment: I want a capitalized R.

Comment: The `Shift` key is producing capitalized letters for all others except R.

Comment: If you boot into Safe Mode does the behavior continue?

Comment: I haven't tried to boot into Safe Mode yet.

Comment: What does it show for you when you press Shift+R on this website https://www.toptal.com/developers/keycode?

Comment: It can only detect Shift, R is not working

Comment: @Fahad - So try it….

Comment: "It can only detect Shift, R is not working" the question wasn't if it is "working", the question is what the website shows when you hold Shift and press R?

Comment: @YisroelTech It only shows Shift when I press Shift-R.

Comment: As Ramhound said, try in safe mode

Comment: Tried in safe mode also but didn't work. All other keys are capitalized except R when pressing the Shift key.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use an external USB keyboard to prove that it is not a hardware issue. If it is, replacing a keyboard is often easy and inexpensive.
2. 1.Do you use [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), [Clavier+](https://gryder.org/software/clavier-plus/?lang=en) or similar keyboard macro app, which might be "stealing" the key press before the system sees it? Turn off the app to test. If that is the issue, remove <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> from the intercept list.
3. Do you use another keyboard layout that might use that key combo for diacritics? If so, [switch layouts](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-between-languages-using-the-language-bar-1c2242c0-fe15-4bc3-99bc-535de6f4f258).

Comment: I have recently changed my previous keyboard for the same issue. Kindly note that, I am having the same issue with **On Screen Keyboard**. I am not using **AutoHotkey** or **Clavier+** or any other keyboard macro app. My keyboard layout is QWERTY. Also note that, I can type capitalized R with `Caps Lock` turned on.

Comment: Not just the physical layout, but the *interpretation* by the Windows layout software: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-change-your-keyboard-layout-windows-10

Comment: I have only one keyboard layout installed which is US QWERTY.