# Dead ctrl keys - how to identify processes absorbing keystrokes

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I am having an odd problem with my <kbd>ctrl</kbd> keys. I find that my control keys (both at once) will stop working globally for a period of time (or a number of keystrokes?), and then sometimes it will be off and on. I often find that if I hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> enough times (20? 40?), it will start working again for a while. When they are not working, both <kbd>ctrl</kbd> keys are dead to any program. Even <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>delete</kbd> does not work.

The problem seems to have started after playing a downloaded game, but it continues even after restarting my machine (with almost all third-party startup processes and services disabled). I might suspect a virus, but Windows Security doesn't identify any. In any case, it seems there must be some process or driver (etc) that is blocking/absorbing the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> keystrokes.

I would be happy to hear thoughts on what might cause this behavior, but my specific question is: is there any way to monitor keystrokes in Windows 10 at a low level and identify processes that might be absorbing keystrokes?

Comment: look in your windows Settings > Accessibility > Keyboard, and see if Sticky Keys, Filter Keys, or Toggle Keys are enabled.

Comment: Always a good thing to check, but all of those are off, as are the keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Do you observe the same behavior when using a different keyboard? If you look at Task Manager, or a more capable alternative such as Process Explorer, can you see any process actions correlating to the keys not working? Does Event Viewer show anything relevant?

Answer (score 1):

Processes intercept key strokes through [hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-hooks). Effectively, there is an event chain. A process can "cut" a link in the chain, inserting itself in the middle. For example, the key down event might have originally gone from app *A* to app *B*. App *X* intercepts message so that they now flow *A* -> *X* ->*B*. Theoretically, one could [examine all processes intercepting key events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56307787/how-to-detect-windows-hooks-intercepting-keypress-events), But apparently, [this is non-trivial](https://superuser.com/questions/449895/how-to-determine-which-app-is-stealing-listening-on-keystroke-key-combinatio).

Instead, open *Task Manager*, on *Details* tab, or *Process Explorer* and go though the list of processes one at a time, looking for anything that might be trapping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, such as *AutoHotkey, Clavier+* or a similar key utility. In particular, also look for anything that game installed...