# Hot key detection on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

Is there any method to detect hotkey binding on Windows 7? AltGr+N should display a } sign on my localized keyboard, but it doesn't display anything or do anything. This behaviour is application independent, doesn't work system wide.
Although if I login to a remote server with remote destop from the same computer, this keybinding works flawlessly on the remote machine.

Any idea?

Hubi

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/11308/how-can-i-determine-which-process-owns-a-hotkey-in-windows