# Disable Windows 8 CTRL+# keyboard shortcut

Tags: windows, windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-8.1

By default, in many web browsers holding down the control key and pressing a number will navigate to that tab (e.g. `CTRL + 4` opens the fourth tab).

However, in Windows 8.1, this keyboard shortcut is overrided by Windows, which uses it to switch windows to different monitors.

How can this shortcut be disabled so other apps can use their intended shortcuts?

Comment: I am finding no evidence that the shorcut in question you describe changes the monitor of the a desktop application, the documentation I discovered,indicates an entirely different shortcut does that. There is no reason there would be two shortcuts to change the monitor which the desktop application would be located on

Comment: In any case, there is still a Windows 8 shortcut that uses those keys. How can it be overridden?

Comment: I am finding no evidence that key combination is even a Windows keyboard shortcut. If you can supply me a page Microsoft that says otherwise...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> is not a [standard Windows 8 shortcut key](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/keyboard-shortcuts#keyboard-shortcuts=windows-8).

You've got a 3rd party application/utility of some kind overriding it.

Check out this other SU question: [How can I determine which process owns a hotkey in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/11308/how-can-i-determine-which-process-owns-a-hotkey-in-windows)

Determine which software that is (by using above info and perhaps `MSconfig`) and reconfigure or stop it.

Comment: Thanks, I looked into this issue more and it seems it is being caused by some OEM software prebuilt (i.e. Lenovo).