# Ctrl-S not working in all (tested) Windows applications

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I mean that pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> will not save current file. If I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (in Notepad++) it will save all files. If I use File->Save menu item - it will save current file.

Depending on this data I could decide that my keyboard working not properly. Is there any tools to test keyboard it self? What can I do to localize the problem?

If it is a keyboard problem - what can I do to fix it?

**UPD**. Just tested in NetBeans, MS Word and Paint: not working as well.

Comment: How about other programs like Paint, Word(Pad), whatever?

Comment: @DanielB Just tested in NetBeans, MS Word and Paint: not working.

Comment: Try [this](http://superuser.com/questions/11308/how-can-i-determine-which-process-owns-a-hotkey-in-windows).

Comment: @DanielB tried: Ctrl-S is in the table but "Reserved by" for this shortcut is empty. Could I do anything else?