# Print Screen key stopped working

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, dropbox, screenshot

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate and the Print Screen key stopped working: no image is put in the keyboard when I hit <kbd>Print Key</kbd>. Nothing happen  when I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>Print Key</kbd> either.

The issue affects the two keyboards that are connected to the computer. Windows' snipping tool works fine. Copy-pasting text works fine too.

I haven't tried to restart the computer, my guess is that it will work then, but I am curious to know what could cause the issue.

Comment: Do you have SkyDrive installed?

Comment: No I don't have skydrive.

Comment: You can see what [program is using the Print Screen hotkey](http://superuser.com/questions/11308/how-can-i-determine-which-process-owns-a-hotkey-in-windows). I know for me, it is SnagIt, the screen capture software. I turn off the Save screenshots feature in Dropbox because of this conflict.

Comment: @sunk818 awesome, that's exactly the kind of software I was looking for! (instead of having to kill running processes…)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After killing my processes one by one, it turned out that Dropbox was causing the issue.

It might be due to the fact that automatically saved in my Dropbox account but it's the first time the issue occurs since I started using this option one month ago.

[image]

Comment: (1.5 year after, Dropbox is still causing this issue.)

Comment: I just discovered this was causing me problems too (on Windows 10), even though this option was disabled. I enabled it, then disabled it again, and that seems to have freed up PrtScn (for now).