# Print screen key is not working on certain applications

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, print-screen

First, let's say I've already read [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/828812/print-screen-key-stopped-working) and [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/11308/how-can-i-determine-which-process-owns-a-hotkey-in-windows) as well with no luck for me.

I've got [Lightshot](https://app.prntscr.com) installed and with the `Print Screen` key mapped, so every time I press that key it simply grays the screen in order to select the zone I want to capture. It works fine on Windows explorer and mostly every single program (Windows 10 Pro running).

Problem comes when I want to capture Visual Studio 2017 or the program I'm actually developing.

Since I'm a developer, I know when and how I'm capturing key events through my code and I know right I'm not capturing at any time the `Print Screen` key.

I thought it might be a problem related with Lightshot itself but seem it isn't, since I press the `Print Screen` key and it effectively performs a screenshot, but not through Lightshot.

This lead me to guess which program could be actually capturing the event, with no luck. I was curious about the Dropbox issue, but I haven't even got the Dropbox client installed.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've got this finally working and it's related with the **administrator privileges** my Visual Studio was running in.

I fixed it applying [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37717649/3563910) closing Lightshot and opening it again.