# Is there any way to reassign Chrome browser's keyboard shortcuts

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

On Windows, my Google Chrome browser is intercepting my keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>O</kbd> .
This is an important key combination in another program I use, but every time I hit that key combination in that other program, it brings up some kind of pink browser window in Chrome.

Is there any way to disable that combination (whatever it is) in Chrome?

Comment: I don't think Ctrl + Alt + O is a default shortcut. Try going to `chrome://extensions` and clicking `Keyboard Shortcuts` at the bottom and check if Ctrl Alt O is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Chrome [keyboard shortcut list](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> is not a Chrome keyboard shortcut.

I also tested Chrome here (Windows 7, latest Chrome), and it doesn't do anything.

So this is some other process (perhaps a Chrome extension you've installed, or something completely separate from Chrome) that's capturing that keyboard shortcut and launching Chrome for whatever reason.

You need to determine what program is actually capturing that shortcut and work form there.  Luckily, there's this handy SuperUser question that covers doing that: [How can I determine which process owns a hotkey in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/11308/how-can-i-determine-which-process-owns-a-hotkey-in-windows)

Comment: You are 100% correct. I could not download HotKeyExplorer, but I hit the combination and brought up the pink Chrome page, and in there was a configuration tab, proudly boasting its ctrl-alt-O capability, which I immediately disabled! Thanks!