# Unknown screenshot program

Tags: windows-8.1, keyboard-shortcuts, screenshot

I've run into some problems on my Windows 8.1 desktop: when I press AltGr+x (which should, on my keyboard layout, produce letter “ź”), some unknown to me screengrabing app starts.

The thing is, I don’t remember installing any, nor can I find any suspicious process. It also doesn’t grab PrintScreen, Alt+PrintScreen etc.

Can one find which program responds that key shortcut? Or possibly one of you could help me identify that program from screenshots?

Before:

[image]
After:

[image]

Comment: What web browser are you using? It could be a browser extension. Does it show up when you're not browsing the web? For instance, if you presses `RightAlt`+`X` on your desktop, does it still show?

Comment: Yes, it does show even then.

Comment: Do you have [SnagIt](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html) installed?

Comment: No. At least, it doesn’t show on Add/Remove Programs list and I don’t have anything with that name on my hard drive.

Comment: This might help - http://superuser.com/a/191090/167187

Comment: Please post the name of the screenshot program with the "Your Answer" form, so other users can benefit from it instead of asking the same question again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That screenshot program was part of a *Performance Monitor* of a *Advance SystemCare 8.1*.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely Advanced SystemCare's Performance Monitor Screenshot function (searching for it and not knowing what program was very aggravating for me as well) and it would happen while gaming, effectively freezing me in place in usually the worst possible way. 
Even after canceling the utility, it forced a system restart before proper keyboard function was restored.

You can change the keybinding by expanding (click the "+" to the right of CPU %) the Performance Monitor then clicking the dropdown under "Screenshot"

I was able to bind it to "None" by making too complex of a key combination (I believe it was Alt+Ctrl+Shift+Keypad_5) though I don't know if this will revert on restarts or updates

Answer (score 0):

[Performance Monitor - minimized mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6O1v.jpg)

[Performance monitor - extended mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IKDU.jpg)

I found how to edit and remove the shortcut, click on the arrow to open the extended Mode of Performance Monitor,  then clicking on the arrow next to the screenshot application icon.

**"Screenshot: Click it to take a screenshot. You can set the hotkey by clicking the drop-down arrow beside it."**

Source:
*https://www.iobit.com/product-manuals/asc-help/*

Answer (score -1):

There might also be a program called "Game Assistant" that is also from IoBit, you can remove that hot key from the settings there.

Look for:

"Game Assistant" or "Superb Game Boost"

I suggest removing both If installed

I was trying what was shown above with no result untill I found out that I had "Game Assistant" installed.