# How to copy current window to clipboard in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, clipboard, print-screen

Last week, I upgraded to Windows 10 from Windows 8.1. In Windows 10, I want to know how to copy a screenshot, directly to the *clipboard*, of *only the current window*. In previous versions of Windows, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>prtsc</kbd> did this.

Potentially relevant info:

- The snipping tool still works fine, but it requires extra steps than what I'm used to.
- I use dropbox.
- I use two monitors.

Here's the behavior I've witnessed:

```
Key(s)    | Windows 8.1                                       | after Windows 10 upgrade
========================================================================================
prtsc     | everything saved to file, copied to clipboard     | everything saved to file
alt+prtsc | current window saved to file, copied to clipboard | everything saved to file
win+prtsc | not sure, never used                              | everything saved to file
```

Comment: Alt+Printscreen works as usual on my W10. What kind of keyboard is it? Desktop or Laptop?

Comment: I am using a laptop, but I use an external keyboard. It doesn't work on either keyboard. The printscreen key works on both. Are you by chance using dropbox?

Comment: The shortcut for this command is identical as previous versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(<kbd>Alt</kbd>+)<kbd>Prt Scr</kbd> still works as it did in previous versions of Windows, and it never automatically saved to a file, as you seem to be suggesting in your chart.

Sounds like you have a 3rd party utility (possibly/probably Dropbox) overriding the regular Print Screen functionality.

Boot Windows into [Safe mode](http://www.7tutorials.com/4-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-10), so that no 3rd party utilities are loading, and it should behave in the default way.

If it turns out it *is* Dropbox that's doing it, you can disable screenshot capture and sharing in Dropbox's preferences.

Comment: Or use this utility to see what is using that prtscrn hotkey http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Info/Windows-Hotkey-Explorer.shtml

Comment: Newer version is now called hotkey commander but is not Free http://hkcmdr.anymania.com/

Comment: @Moab Good idea. Here's another SU question regarding that: [How can I determine which process owns a hotkey in Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/11308/how-can-i-determine-which-process-owns-a-hotkey-in-windows)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007, disabling the dropbox screenshot preference returned the functionality.