# ALT+PrtScr doesn't work

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

When I press <kbd>PrtScr</kbd>, a screenshot of the whole screen is placed on the Clipboard. And when I press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> it's placed in the screenshots folder. But when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> - **nothing** happens ("nothing" includes that there is nothing on the clipboard which was mentioned above, of course). Not even a screenshot of the whole screen.

I've tried pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> along with that combination, and <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, but to no avail.

Is there some Windows setting for disabling that that might have been set? Might there be an application listening to that keyboard shortcut? A registry setting for it?

Comment: Are you using right or left Alt? If you have "international US-keyboard" the right Alt means Ctrl-Alt.

Comment: Other possibility is that the hotkey has been registered by another program running in the background. You may clean boot Windows to test, or check Alt + PrntScrn functionality in Safe mode.

Comment: @EmilioPlatzer Thanks. But I tried both. And I have a regular US English keyboard.

Comment: Here are a step by step instruction: http://www.howtogeek.com/107965/how-to-add-any-application-shortcut-to-windows-explorers-context-menu/

Comment: `Alt+PrnScr` will place the screenshot of the current window in clipboard. You need to paste to some app to get the screenshot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy current window to clipboard in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/983065/how-to-copy-current-window-to-clipboard-in-windows-10)

Comment: [Print screen not working on windows 10](https://superuser.com/q/1210789/241386)