# Print screen not working on windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, screenshot, print-screen

I'm using Windows 10. When I try to take print screen with <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>, nothing happens

I tried these shorcuts

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>
- <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>
- <kbd>Func</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>
- <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Func</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>

But this is not working. Is there any driver required for that?

**Links:**

- http://www.digitalcitizen.life/4-ways-take-screenshots-windows-8-81-using-built-tools
- https://www.howtogeek.com/226280/how-to-take-screenshots-in-windows-10/
- etc...

But no luck. Help appreciated!! :)

Comment: Is it possible to provide what type of keyboard you are using?  There may be an extra step we are missing.  Like the possibility of a `FN` or *function key*.  Also, could you please clarify what you mean by "Not Responding"?  Does nothing happen when you try to paste?

Comment: @CheesusCrust thanks for your asking.  Its DELL keyboard.. "Not responding" I mean nothing happens when pressing these above short cut key

Comment: Well, it should be storing a image of your screen into the *Clipboard*.  Go ahead and try opening **Paint** or a text editor like **Microsoft Word** and paste using `Ctrl + V` or `Right Click` and select *Paste*

Comment: @CheesusCrust: I suggest you put that first comment into your answer. This question/answer is near the top in Google's results when one searches for this topic. And many of us do know about pasting the image, and our problem was that the new keyboard required Fn to be pressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hitting <kbd>PrntScrn</kbd> alone will only store an image of the screen into your *Clipboard*, which you would then have to paste into a document.

If you open up **Paint** or anything else that supports images, you can paste the last screenshot you took by either pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or `Right Click` and selecting *Paste* from the menu.

**Paint** actually has a large button on the top left of the application window that allows you to paste as well.

[image: [Placeholder for image since Imgur is returning an error right now.]]

Answer (score 1):

Most of the shortcuts in your list work, you just need to read a little bit more carefully the articles you linked

> The first method is also the best known and it works in all versions of Windows: on your keyboard, press the <kbd>PrtScn</kbd> (Print Screen) key or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScn</kbd> keys. Windows creates a screenshot of the whole screen and saves it to the clipboard. It is not stored as a file on your hard drive. **Then, open an image editing program like Paint and paste the picture from the clipboard.** Then, you can save it as a file and even do some basic editing.

https://www.digitalcitizen.life/4-ways-take-screenshots-windows-8-81-using-built-tools

> ## To Save Your Screenshot as a File
>
> Press the “<kbd>Windows logo key</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScn</kbd>.” If you’re using a tablet, press the “<kbd>Windows logo button</kbd>+<kbd>volume down button</kbd>.” On some laptops and other devices, you may need to press the “<kbd>Windows logo key</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScn</kbd>” or “<kbd>Windows logo key</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScn</kbd>” keys instead. Check your laptop’s manual for more information.
>
> The screen will dim for a moment, and **you will see the screenshot appear as a file in a folder entitled “Screenshots”, inside your default “Pictures” folder**. The screenshot is automatically labeled with a number.

https://www.howtogeek.com/226280/how-to-take-screenshots-in-windows-10/

[image: Windows screenshot photos]

In short, <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> combinations without <kbd>Windows</kbd> stores the image in the **clipboard**, otherwise it'll be stored in the ***pictures library*** and **not** your desktop with <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScn</kbd>. Or just use <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> and you'll have various choices of copying the screenshot to clipboard, editing or saving it as a new file

Answer (score 0):

I found that the batteries in my keyboard needed to be changed even though the keyboard worked other than the <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> key. Once the batteries were changed the <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> key worked.  Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score -2):

Use the keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScn</kbd>. In Windows, you can also take screenshots of the active window. Open the window that you want to capture and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScn</kbd> on your keyboard

Comment: `Alt+Prntscrn` not working in my case

Comment: AFAIK that doesn't *save* the image..

Comment: use Alt + PrtScn and then past it in a word file it will work.