# How can I determine which process owns a hotkey in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

One of my highly used hotkey got hijacked by another program in Ubuntu. But I don't know which program it is. By some researching, I found there is a discussion for Windows. ([Here](https://superuser.com/questions/11308/how-can-i-determine-which-process-owns-a-hotkey-in-windows)). But I could not find related solution for Ubuntu.

So, Is there some way in Ubuntu to determine that: when I press a key combination, which program consumes this key combination?

---

The [linked question](https://superuser.com/questions/1130728/what-is-the-name-of-this-ubuntu-program) does solved my situation. But I think this question here should be kept as a separate thread, because finding a generic solution here will help solve other hotkey related problems in Ubuntu.

Comment: You asked this twice: http://superuser.com/questions/1130728/what-is-the-name-of-this-ubuntu-program   - the other has more detail but you should have edited this one rather than posting a new question.