# What is the name of this Ubuntu program?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys, clipboard

A couple month ago I installed a bunch of clipboard manager programs in Ubuntu, tried them out and then removed them. I must have missed one of these and now it keeps bug me in my daily usage. I need some help to identify the name of this program because the program itself provides very limited information.

This clipboard program has below characteristics:
1. It occupies hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>. When I press this hotkey, the clipboard history will pop out. It happens in bash, Chrome, Eclipse IDE, and etc, wherever it is text inputable. This is kind of annoying because it overrides my other hotkeys inside these applications.
2. Very laconic UI. Like below picture, with only a line "Select to paste", then listing out the clipboard history. There is no program information whatsoever. Right clicking on it and no menu are shown at all.

[image]

---

So far I have tried below ways to identify this program:
1. Browse system monitor for processes with names that could be correlated.
2. Browse through my installation log (dpkg.log) to find my installation history. Without luck, the log is lost.
But I was not successful.

Comment: Open up Keyboard and check to see if the shortcut is assigned there.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I checked and it is not there. This is not a system keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Debian Code Search](https://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=%22Select+to+paste%22), this is the clipboard plugin for the *fcitx* input method (which is normally used for multi-language keyboard input).

Comment: Precisely, I fixed it by turn it off in fcitx. Furthermore, the code search is a good generic approach.