# Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S hotkey not working in Windows 10 at all (not even in safe mode)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, hotkeys

I am using the Romanian (programmers) keyboard in Windows 10 so that I can insert special characters using the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>). All of them work EXCEPT for <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (that should insert capital S-comma or Ș). From my understanding so far, this is equivalent to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. My thought was that some other program had registered the combination and when I press it, it goes to that program instead.

What I have tried so far, unsuccessfully:

- searching for hotkeys in the registry using nirsoft's RegScanner - nothing found
- searching for hotkeys using nirsoft's HotKeyList - nothing found
- searching for hotkeys using a vbs script from a superuser/stackoverflow post (can't remember which, I've read so many topics)
- closing all user programs one by one with task manager and trying the hotkey to see if I closed the culprit (though this did not work as well as planned, as some services would keep restarting)
- rebooting in safe mode did not make it work!
- using autohotkey to insert the character - nothing happens

Basically the combination seems to be dead. I am not even sure if it registers. On Linux it works fine, and on Windows <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> + other characters works fine. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> also works fine (without the <kbd>Shift</kbd>).

I am running out of ideas. I really thought autohotkey would work, but kept it as a last resort.
Strangely enough, autohotkey displayed the following behavior:

- setting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to send the character Ș did nothing
- setting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to do something else (like display a messagebox) did nothing
- setting some other combination (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>) to send the character Ș would actually trigger the hotkey for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (so it would display the messagebox I set earlier).
- setting some other combination to send the unicode for Ș (U+0218) would work!
- setting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to send the unicode for Ș would not work

So for the moment I have it set in autohotkey with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> since it's above the S on the keyboard, but it's less than ideal. Also, I would really want to find out the cause of this.

Comment: Check the answers in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/11308/how-can-i-determine-which-process-owns-a-hotkey-in-windows), [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1241607/remove-unwanted-app-hotkey-in-windows/) and [this](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/33669/tool-to-list-all-current-windows-10-hotkeys) question for possible solutions

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following AutoHotKey definition?

```
+<^>!s::­Ș
```

For me, it works nicely, <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> produces `Ș`, in line with expectations from [AltGr key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key).

Note: Do not press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, it is not the same as the above. For native Windows apps, they are not equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

Using Alt-Ctrl combinations is not recommended. Those can have a wide range of effect in many general use programs.

Use the defaults instead. When you switch language to Ro, those will work: `"[];'\"` are the equivalent of `"ăîșțâ"`. Shift+those works for the CAPS version.

No need for Alt or Ctrl whatsoever.

Comment: That's the issue, I don't want to use the old keyboard layout because I code a lot. And it's much easier to remember the special characters as AltGr + their non special version. I want to know how to find out which program is preventing the specified hotkey from being issued.

Comment: @Overmind – I find this answer misleading, because it ignores long-year principles of international keyboards supported by Microsoft and also by other platforms. AltGr is their way to type national characters and it is generally equivalent to Ctrl+Left Alt when related keyboard layout is active. Request of the OP is therefore legitimate. Regarding your concern, most apps recognize between Ctrl+Left Alt (as compatible way of pressing Ctrl+Alt) and AltGr which produces national characters. The only "dumb" apps who confuse this are multi-platform ports like for example Eclipse IDE.