# Remove unwanted app hotkey in windows

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I'm using Windows 10 and an app I recently installed has set `CTRL+M+O` as a hotkey for launching itself, overriding a common shortcut for Visual Studio (collapse to definition). The problem is, I don't know how to disable it.

I tried searching for an .ink that had this assigned in Properties, but the only one I could find hasn't defined any hotkey. I couldn't find a shortcut manager in Windows to disable these "user-mapped" shortcuts. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try using **Shortcut Key Explorer** from the good folks at RJL Software, which will scan your PC and find shortcuts with hotkeys saved in it.

http://www.rjlsoftware.com/software/utility/shortcutkeys/download.shtml

> Simply run Shortcut Key Explorer and it will automatically load the
>   existing shortcut keys and display them in an easy to read list. From
>   this list you can double-click on any item and edit the properties of
>   the Windows shortcut. This is great for troubleshooting duplicate
>   shortcut keys or shortcut keys you did not even know existed.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, the shortcut keys will only work if the shortcut lives on the Desktop or in the Start Menu. So to find all possible culprits, you can open up a command prompt and then run this:

```
dir /s /b "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\*.lnk"
dir /s /b "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\*.lnk"
```

This will display all shortcut files on the Desktop and in the Start Menu. Look for one which matches whichever application is opening up. Then open up the shortcut and remove the shortcut key.

Answer (score 3):

Open the App's properties, go to Shortcut and in the Shortcut Key field, edit it to something else. Visual Studio should start working as it was prior to the install

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Basing on the response from Jim's [post](https://superuser.com/a/1320005/26302)
here are the commands for powershell and win10 that worked for me:

```
dir $env:APPDATA"\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\*.lnk"
dir $env:USERPROFILE"\Desktop\*.lnk"
```