# There is a hotkey intercepting the tilde key on my Windows PC. I can't figure out how to disable it

Tags: windows, keyboard, hotkeys

### Problem

I cannot press Shift+` on my PC to create the tilde character. This problem happens with both my physical keyboard and the on-screen keyboard. If I plug my physical keyboard into another computer, it works fine.

### Troubleshooting

#### Language Switcher Keys

A common solution I see posted is that people have completely disabled their backtick key to allow them to switch languages. That is not my problem:

[image: Language switcher keys are disabled]

#### Shortcut (.lnk) keyboard shortcut

Someone else [recommended using a tool](https://superuser.com/a/1241667/307789) to find shortcuts (.lnk files) with keyboard shortcuts set up on them. This tool has not found anything.

[image: Shortcut Key Explorer comes up empty]

#### Spy++

I have tried using Spy++ to track down which window is intercepting the key as a hotkey. I found solutions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829007/find-out-what-process-registered-a-global-hotkey-windows-api/43645062#43645062) recommending this approach.

And this does indeed show that the key combo is being intercepted as a hotkey:

[image: a list of WM_HOTKEY messages from Spy++]

but if I follow the links through this tool to find the specific Window + Process, it just points to "Explorer". I don't know where to go from here:

[image: WM_HOTKEY message properties]

[image: Window Properties]

[image: Process Properties]

### UPDATE:

#### Safe Mode

I had tried this before when I last tried troubleshooting this issue but I tried it again: Safe Mode does not fix the issue. If I boot into safe mode, I still cannot type the tilde.

#### OpenArk

I found another resource that recommended a program called [OpenArk](https://github.com/BlackINT3/OpenArk/releases). I was a bit wary of this but it seems to play nice. I ran the tool to detect hotkeys and it did indeed find the hotkey registered. And to be clear, it is `C:\Windows\explorer.exe` and not some fake one, as far as I can tell:

[image: explorer.exe has registered Shift+Oem3]

This tool lets me delete the hotkey from the registry - and this *actually worked!!!* `~~~~~~~~` I'm typing these right now from the problem PC!

The problem though is that *if I restart my computer, the hotkey comes back*. So it's a temporary fix but not one I'm satisfied with. But I think it confirms that it's definitely some hotkey at play.

Next I'd like to figure out what is registering the hotkey to begin with. Is there perhaps a mechanism to log which processes are registering hotkeys?

Comment: The ~ key can be used to write ñ. If you press ~n do you get the ñ? If so, your keyboard language is set to an international standard such as US international. If you add US and switch to that, I suspect the ~ key to work normally.

Comment: What happens if you press Shift+` twice?

Comment: @LPChip that does not happen. I am going to press those keystrokes now: n.

Comment: @harrymc nothing happens. two separate hotkey events are registered in Spy++ when I do that.

Comment: Does this happen if booting in Safe mode?

Comment: In Task Manager, Details, look for any process that might be stealing those key codes. You can kill a suspicious process and test tilde.

Comment: @harrymc it still happens in safe mode, just tried it.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik the issue I have is that it appears to be the explorer process itself that has bound the hotkey. I have found that using these third party tools that show it is the process intercepting the hotkey message.

Comment: Added some additional troubleshooting steps, including a temporary fix - I found a tool that lets me delete the hotkey, but it comes back when I restart my PC. now I just need to figure out what's setting it.

Comment: Which tool is that?

Comment: details are in the OP :) but it's OpenArk64

Comment: What is your language and keyboard layout? Do you know what registry modification is done by OpenArk64?

Comment: @harrymc english, US qwerty. I looked into the code of OpenArk, I'm not super familiar with its domain and the APIs it's working with but it _appears_ to me that it's just clearing the individual hotkey registration with the running process. And I can kinda confirm that because if I manually restart explorer.exe, the hotkey comes back and I can't type tilde anymore.

Comment: It seems like some tool integrates into explorer and sets up a dynamic keyboard hook. Perhaps [ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) could find more info. A pity that OpenArk64 doesn't give any hint of what it's actually eradicating.

Comment: You can use a program like  [SharpKeys](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys) to see whether the key is assigned the same way in both computers:  [Screenshot SharpKeys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPOXr.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Xbox Game Bar was configured with the hotkey.

I saw someone recommend checking Xbox Game Bar for shortcuts. And sure enough, I found the shortcut for Shift+` was set up on the game bar

I don't remember setting this up, perhaps I fat-fingered something. I also checked this screen multiple times - but there is a *SCROLL BAR* very subtly hidden on the right side of the dialog. This screenshot shows how the window looked to me when I opened it just now and *happened* to finally notice the scroll bar:

[image: ugh]

And if I scroll down...

[image: there it is in all of its fine glory]

I'm very annoyed but also very glad to have finally found this!