# Ctrl+Shift+F stopped working

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in various programs to perform a 'Find in Files' function. (Visual Studio & Atom for example)

- Other <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> functions work (+<kbd>H</kbd>
  & +<kbd>G</kbd> for instance work fine in those same programs)
- Tried this same keyboard in another system and
  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> works fine
  (<kbd>F</kbd> key works fine in those same programs)
- Tried removing the device in the device manager for the keyboard
  and re-discovering
- Tried resetting the settings configurations for the programs
  that used this shortcut - nothing
- Tried this online keyboard tester (http://en.key-test.ru/) and
  the shortcut works there
- Windows On-Screen Keyboard also *cannot* perform
  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in those programs
- Tried repairing Visual Studio which essentially re-installs it and reinstalling Atom

I'm not sure what else to try. It stopped working when I upgraded from one Visual Studio version to the next available however it also simultaneously stopped working in Atom. Are there some other areas of settings that need to be flushed? I have to assume that was just a coincidence...

Comment: I had a similar issue today after a Windows 10 patch upgrade.  Suddenly, Ctrl+E and Ctrl+F stopped working.  It was bizarre.  I followed instructions from this answer https://superuser.com/a/1204019/81913 to run Visual Studio Spy++.  Strangely, as soon as enabled logging for *all* messages, my hot keys immediately stated working correctly again.  I never found the root cause.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The culprit was Razer Cortex which had an FPS toggle claiming the hotkey...

Discovered using this method: https://superuser.com/a/1204019/160458

I'm not sure why it worked through Chrome when testing the keyboard online however.

Comment: Wow what a stupid piece of crap Cortex is.  Uninstalling it now.  I discovered the issue while running X11 server and assumed it was a Linux key bindings issue, and wasted so many hours trying to figure it out.

Comment: Aha, you saved me! Thanks for posting a solution!

Comment: This has ruined my VSCode experience until I found this and closed Razer Cortex. What an annoying problem. Thank you!

Comment: This helped me :) Additionally you have to restart the Visual Studio to take the Ctrl + Shift + F to work.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could change the shortcut that Razer Cortex has like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the archives: I tripped on this bug with a software of mine today, I was still running Windows 10 1909 (not sure why Windows auto-update hadn't happened yet). I updated my Windows to 20H2 using the Update Assistant, and joyfully note: the bug seems to have been fixed by Microsoft: KeyDown-events for CTRL-ALT-SHIFT-F do occur again.