# windowkey + print screen not working on windows 10

Tags: windows, hotkeys, screenshot, print-screen

I'm using windows 10.

When I try to take screen shot with windows key + PrtScr key, nothing happens.

PrtScr key copies screen to a clipboard. Shift + windows key + s also works.

I want to know why windows key + PrtScr doesn't work and how to fix it.

- I know windows key + PrtScr key directly saves screen to some folder and I have used this few times it just doesn't work now.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser! It works fine on my side. Have you recently installed new software or made changes to the OS?

Comment: can you check this to see who captured that `Windows+PrtScr` key? [How can I determine which process owns a hotkey in Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/11308/241386)

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio No. I updated window few days ago and that's it.

Comment: @phuclv I'm using windows 10, the writer said it might cause problem so I'm not going to try that.

Comment: Have you used Win+Prt Sc on your current pc earlier?

Comment: Also, see the answer https://superuser.com/a/1598341/822976 to question posted by phuclv, this answer is for windows 10, so won't cause issues.

Comment: @EricLee read the below answers in that question. There are tons of solutions for Windows 10

Comment: @TontyTon Yes I used it often and it saved picture to screenshot folder.

Comment: @phuclv I downloaded the gui version of Hotkey Detective.
I run the 64 version with administrator and it pops a program. 
But it didn't show any. It doesn't work only for this windows + PrstScr
It works with shift + windows + s. It shows its in explorer.exe

Comment: Tell the exact version of windows installed by entering 'winver' in 'Run'(Win+R).

Comment: @TontyTon version is 20H2(OS build 19042.928)

Comment: Do screen dim or not? If screen dims on pressing Win+PrtScrn maybe screenshot save location changed for some reason.

Comment: @TontyTon screen doesn't dim. It used to but now anymore since it started not working.

Comment: Use https://www.keyboardtester.com/ to confirm that your Prt Scr key is working.

Comment: @TontyTon I used the site you linked, I tested windows key + prtscr, they show as green key. I also tested them separately and both work.

Comment: @TontyTon also about phuclv answer, I read his post and I don't understand how to run it. I don't know how to run his code.