# How to identify what program is stealing keyboard input shortcuts

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, nvidia-geforce

[Win 10 Home, 64-bit, Build 20H2, fully updated + MS Office +...]

I just updated NVidia GeForce experience to V3.22.0.32 and it has provided/updated the in-game overlay that uses a number of keyboard shortcuts commonly used by other applications (e.g. Alt +F8, Alt+F11 in Excel).

**NVidia GeForce experience steals them**: I realised this when Alt+F11 etc. no longer worked in Excel and recalled that NVidia was updated just last night.

By going into Settings for the ing-name overlay and hitting spacebar for each selected NVidia keyboard shortcut I was able to set them all (except Alt-Z to open the overlay!) to None and so restored the functionality of all my other apps.

Apart from being absolutely appalling behaviour on NVidia's part - for which they should be loudly rebuked - it raises this important question for future reference in cases where the culprit is not so obvious:

**how can one identify what program is stealing/eating/consuming keyboard shortcuts?**

(NB the overlay can be disabled in GeForce settings, under General, but something changed without my permission - either it was enabled by the update or keyboard theft was added to an enabled overlay; either way it was NVidia's fault)

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/11308/how-can-i-determine-which-process-owns-a-hotkey-in-windows

Comment: @DrMoishePippik HotKey detective at that link seems to do exactly what I wanted; thanks. Standalone binaries here: https://github.com/ITachiLab/hotkey-detective/releases

Answer (score 2):

**Posting this as solution for further issues. All credits go to [Dr. Moishe Pippik](https://superuser.com/users/401553/drmoishe-pippik) and [Hans-Peter Störr](https://superuser.com/users/9866/hans-peter-st%c3%b6rr)**

Application confirmed by OP to be working on Windows 10: [HotKey Detective (Git)](https://github.com/ITachiLab/hotkey-detective/releases)

[Find out what process registered a global hotkey? (Windows API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829007/find-out-what-process-registered-a-global-hotkey-windows-api/834661).

Comment: -1 because the warning is misapplied: HotKey Explorer is not reliable > Win 8; I am already using HotKey Detective on Win 10 successfully,

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Updated the answer to confirm it working on Win 10.