# What's wrong with my CTRL keys?

Tags: windows, windows-11

The <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key on my keyboard has been annoying me for days now. Commands like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> don't work sometimes and its results in just <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>C</kbd> being printed on the screen.

This happens with both <kbd>CTRL</kbd> keys (both left and right). I've removed and cleaned both keys on the keyboard, but this does not resolve the problem. The normal behavior for these modifier keys work only some of the time, so the problem is intermittent.

I have a dualboot of Windows and Linux, and the modifier keys work great on the Linux installation. I've reinstalled Windows in an attempt to fix this, but it's still not working.

Comment: Since the Ctrl key works in Linux, you *know* there is no issue with the physical keyboard or related circuitry; the issue *must* be something in Windows stealing the key press. Look to 1. Windows Accessibility Features, such as Sticky Keys: https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/windows-10-accessibility-features-for-disabled-people/ and 2. Third-party tools that hook into the keyboard, such as AutoHotkey and Clavier+.

Comment: check who steals the combo: [How to identify what program is stealing keyboard input shortcuts](https://superuser.com/q/1647133/241386), [How can I determine which process owns a hotkey in Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/11308/241386)

Comment: @DrMoishePippik that doesent seem to be the issue. Plus i already did a complete reset of windows purging all files and software and this is still happening

Comment: Well, if it's not a problem in Linux, there's very very low chance it's a rather weird hardware issue. Are you sure you reset everything on Windows?

Comment: Hi @Destroy666, yes, i did a reset from settings, purging all files and apps. I did not do a  clean install. I'm planning on trying a repair install because this problem started after a rough shutdown where my pc resumed from disk check utility.

Comment: If you removed everything, you might as well do a clean install, yes.

Comment: @Destroy666, i'm trying to avoid messing up my linux partition, thats why i've been avoiding a clean install. But if all else fails, might as well

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that one of the Sticky Keys Settings are producing the symptom you are experiencing.  In `Settings`, go to `Keyboard` and

- Turn off `Sticky` settings
- Turn off `Toggle` Settings
- Turn off `Filter` settings
- Turn on `Make it easier to type` (turning these on will show you if this feature is the cause).

[image]

Comment: HI, turns out it was a broken update from HP or microsoft. After a while, i got an update for my HDI devices on windows update and its been working since then