# Ctrl-Shift-T shortcut stopped working in ALL programs (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

At least, it stopped working in Chrome and VSCode. I use this shortcut frequently so this is pretty painful. I'm using a new computer but I'm pretty sure it was working at some point, right now Ctrl-Shift-T does absolutely nothing as far as I'm aware. Ctrl-T and Shift-T both work perfectly fine on their own, and so does Ctrl-Shift-N, so this is strange to me. I read online that it could be caused by some input languages settings, but [I don't see how that could be the case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzEl2.png). I installed the following software, maybe that has something to do with it?

- NZXT CAM (enabled on startup)
- Intel Extreme Tuning Utility
- OBS
- Synergy (shares mouse & keyboard between computers)
- TechPowerUp GPU-Z
- HWMonitor
- MSI Afterburner
- L-Connect (enabled on startup)
- Intel Driver & Support Assistant

Answer (score 3):

The issue was L-Connect. I found this out thanks to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1204019/1396665). There was no setting I could change to fix it, but installing the newer version of the program (L-Connect 2) worked: Ctrl-Shift-T is now working properly for me. (I also had to update the firmware to ensure compatibility between L-Connect 2 and my fans, since they're "UNI HUB without SL Mark", which is described in situation 2 [in their guidebook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lZDI9FQEHRptOKHJTeL8_Qf7os3I1hU0/view).)

Comment: The problem is that L-Connect 1 is displayed [on this website](https://lian-li.com/product/uni-fan-sl/), and the only way you'd even know about L-Connect 2 is if you read the Guidebook. Either L-Connect 1 should be updated to fix the Ctrl-Shift-T hotkey override, or the download link should be replaced with L-Connect 2.

Comment: omg THANK you! This Q&A made me look up "L-Connect", which seems to be something related to the computer case or motherboard. This inspired me to simply try changing the physical USB port my keyboard was plugged into, which immediately fixed my problem! My issue was that the `T` key wouldn't be recognised by any software whatsoever if the `Ctrl` key was already pressed (every other `Ctrl+...` combination worked perfectly). I think whatever OS-driver weirdness happens upon USB disconnect/reconnect fixed a pernicious keyboard firmware/driver bug.

Comment: I've plugged my keyboard back into the same physical port it used to be in, and it's now working fine again. A truly bizarre bug with an incredibly opaque fix that has taught me a valuable lesson: if it's possible that the problem is with firmware/drivers, try swapping USB ports to trigger Windows' automatic driver (re)installation routine - a hell of a lot faster than finding drivers from some obscure website, or trying to write new firmware onto hardware memory!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue; the offending program was WinCompose. In general, anything that messes with keyboard input in the background is a likely candidate.