# Ctrl + Shift + T starts "EXPLORER" task instead of reopening closed browser tab

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I've done everything from here -> [How can I determine which process owns a hotkey in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/11308/how-can-i-determine-which-process-owns-a-hotkey-in-windows?newreg=c5aca547efbc469bbbfb0fcc507f53bd)
and it turns out "Explorer" is using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> key bind. When I've terminated the task I was actually able to reopen a closed browser tab.
The thing is - I can't recall ever assigning that key bind...
Is it possible to remove/revert it? I would like to reopen closed tabs in Chrome/Edge etc. instead of launching some process in Explorer with that keybind.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on windows, you can remove the keybind from explorer by following these steps:

- Use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> key combination to open the
  explorer.
- Right click on the explorer icon in the taskbar, a menu will appear.
- Right click on the program name in the menu (it will be present just above the pin/unpin button) and then left click on
  properties, the properties window will open.
- Go to Shortcut tab and change the "Shortcut key" parameter value to None by pressing backspace.

[Visual aid for the above steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmCxW.jpg)

Comment: It doesn't actually open an Explorer as per your screenshot. It opens a process that can be seen in the task manager.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your task manager?